# How configure Nginx proxy_pass in for Tomcat

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ubuntu, tomcat, nginx

I want to configure `proxy_pass` for `Nginx` for the `Apache Tomcat` server. 
I have the Angular application launched on the Nginx application and I have the Spring Boot application run on the Tomcat server.

This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;



server  {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

}
}


}
```

Ind I do not understand why do not send `API` request on my Spring Boot app. 
I do not have any error on the log on the `nginx` or `Tomcat` server

Comment: press F12 on browser and see if api is being hit and what url browser is invoking

Comment: Invoking URL of my domain name and path of API call.
example: `http://mydomane/api/auth/validateLogin`

Comment: try using curl **curl** **http://mydomane/api/auth/validateLogin** and check

Comment: I changed on this and now this work. 
`server  {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
server_name  domain.com  www.http://domain

proxy_redirect           off;
    proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header         Host $http_host;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

}
}`